# How to sort dataGridView in descending order by a specific column and rank them?

Tags: c#, mysql, sorting, datagridview

I am trying to create a leaderboard based on player's High score.

Each player's scores are entered randomly into DB.

I need to sort them based on their high score and also rank them.

this is my table structure 
[image]

Here i want to display player_ID, player_name, player_nick and HP in datagridview.

any help is appreciated.

> string query1 = "SELECT player_ID'Player ID',player_name'Player
>   Name',player_nick'Nick Name',HP'High Score' FROM player_profile ORDER
>   BY HP DESC";

My work so far, i don't know how to rank

Comment: If you are getting information from database you can use order by.

Comment: @KratosMafia ok... then how to rank them?

Comment: You should not assume @tdbeckett is being lazy.   What he might be getting at (as I am) is that you should show the C# code you have so far. We assume you already know how to *retrieve* the data, since you've only asked about sorting/ranking.   The answers you seek depend on whether you are a.) constructing a query in C# & sending to the DB, invoking a stored proc., or using an ORM. And b.) what permissions you have in the DB (e.g., can you create a new stored proc?)  As it is, your question is far too open-ended.

Comment: I would have thought the answer might have been worth an upvote especially considering how little help you got initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL to provide the rank with a user variable (I think there are also  some  Rank() functions).  From something like Workbench:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT Name, HP, @rank:=@rank+1 As Rank FROM Demo ORDER BY HP ASC
```

You can also do it from code, with one small change:

```
string SQL = @"SET @rank=0; 
               SELECT Name, HP, StartDate, @rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
               FROM Demo ORDER BY HP DESC;";

using (MySqlConnection dbcon = mySqlDB.GetMySQLConnection())
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL,dbcon))
{
    dbcon.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    dgv1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Results:

[image]

There is no Rank column in the table, that is added via the SQL statement above.

If you have ties, it gets more complicated.  You'd have to introduce some other vars to track when the HP/Score changes and increment @rank only then.  If you want to skip a rank on ties ({1,2,2,4} vs {1,2,2,3}) you'd have to also add a counter.

The one thing is that you have to allow user vars which can be specified in the connection string:

```
Server=SvrAddr;Database=myDB;Uid=myUsr;Pwd=myPass;Allow User Variables=True";
```

According to [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)  the option is available as of version 5.2.2

---

[This Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333697/1070452) shows how to skip having to initialize the `rank` var:

```
string SQL = @"SELECT Name, HP, StartDate, @rank:=@rank+1 As Rank 
               FROM Demo, (SELECT @rank := 0) r ORDER BY HP DESC;";
```

Adding `(SELECT @rank := 0) r` prevents having to explicitly declare it.  Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds the data to the dataGridView and then answers your question at the end.

```
// Add columns to the dataGridView
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("player_ID", "player_ID");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("player_name", "player_name");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("player_nick", "player_nick");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("HP", "HP");

// Add some data to the dataGridView
object[] rowData = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

rowData[0] = 0;     // Player_ID
rowData[1] = "Pancho";        // Player_Name
rowData[2] = "Speedy";        // Player Nick
rowData[3] = Convert.ToDecimal("58.7");     // HP
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);

rowData[0] = 1;
rowData[1] = "Ramon";
rowData[2] = "Sleepy";
rowData[3] = Convert.ToDecimal("39.6");     // HP
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);

rowData[0] = 2;
rowData[1] = "Cimitrio";
rowData[2] = "Grumpy";
rowData[3] = Convert.ToDecimal("41.2");     // HP
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);

rowData[0] = 3;                 // Player_ID
rowData[1] = "Panfilo";         // Player_Name
rowData[2] = "Gummy Bear";        // Player Nick
rowData[3] = Convert.ToDecimal("61.5");     // HP
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);

// Sort dataGridView by HP
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

// Add rank column            
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Rank", "Rank");

// Rank players
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Rank"].Value = Convert.ToString(i+1);
}
```